# how to connect to Oracle application expres database

Tags: database, oracle, express, connect

I've signed up into Oracle Application Express for my school education purposes (I need free Oracle db hosting). I am developing web application which I would like to be coonected to db which Oracle given me with App Express. My problem is that I don't know where to get connection string for this db or if it is even possible to get.

Thank you very much :)

Regards, bakua

Comment: An option is to set up Oracle 11g XE on Amazon Web Services EC2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you're trying to use the database provided at apex.oracle.com as just a standard Oracle db and build your own independent web app using that as the backend db? If so, you can't. The apex.oracle.com setup is designed purely for learning and experimenting with apex.

This is confirmed here

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=905176

If I understood your question!

I'm not aware of any free Oracle hosting other than downloading free versions from Oracle and hosting on your own computer.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I wanted to know :)